# How can I cut a graph representing 2D positions into two sub-graphs?

Tags: algorithm, procedural-generation, graph

I have a graph where each node is associated with a 2D position. I would like to use a finite line to "cut" this graph into two halves, as shown below:

[image: 2d Graph]

Note that the cutting line does have a direction. All vertices in that direction remain and aren't cut away.

How can I implement this?

Comment: This is somewhat ambiguous. If the red line were just a tiny bit lower, would you want that dangling edge that would be left? Or does it have a grid structure to maintain?

Comment: This caes is ambiguous, it doesn't have to maintain a grid structure. If the red line were a bit lower there would be an edge to the right top corner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the algorithm I see happening in your question:
(I use "inside" meaning specifically not ON the cut line but only inside it)

```
P = Plane To Cut Across.
For every edge in the graph as Line A->B {
    A_inside = Is point A inside plane P?
    if (point B is on line P && !A_inside) return nothing;

    B_inside = Is point B inside plane P?
    if (point A is on line P && !B_inside) return nothing;

    if (A_inside == B_inside) {
        return Line A->B
    }
    Q = Intersection of line P and line A->B
    if (A_inside) {
        return Line A->Q
    } else {
        return Line Q->B
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, what about the connections that are cutted (notice the lines on the cut line)

Comment: I added some logic at the top to account for deleting the lines with one (or more vertices) exactly on the plane, and the other outside it.